# What Is The Motor Club of America?

Tags: scams, pyramid-scheme

So this entire company screams pyramid scheme to me, the only problem is that an overwhelming amount of people seem to be getting roped into this referral based AAA-like service all over every crevice of the internet (mostly Facebook) and I can't get a grasp on how people don't see this is a huge scam.

These people swear by it, and I'm also seeing posts by people that I used to know in grade school. (I thought their accounts got hacked until I saw a real video of the person giving an explanation about how it only costs $40 to sign up and that you get $80 back for each referral).

Their website is listed located here: http://www.motorclubamerica.net/

Am I wrong? What am I missing that people still fall into schemes like this?

Comment: Related: [What warnings would you tell a friend about to enter a multi-level marketing (MLM) business venture?](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/6456/10997)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Note: I have never heard of this company before this question was asked.  These are my thoughts based on a quick review of their website.

It seems that Motor Club of America is a roadside assistance service company, similar to AAA.  It is ridiculously expensive: $20 per month for their "Total Security" plan, or $240 per year.  This is about double what the highest level of AAA membership costs.

As you noticed, they recruit people to sell their Total Security plan in a Multilevel Marketing type scheme.  Your Facebook friends and acquaintances that "swear by it" are simply being paid to do so.  It's nothing more than that.  Their job is to fill up your Facebook feed with a sales pitch for an overpriced product.

Of course, *you* don't need to be told this, but selling overpriced products to your friends is not the best way to make money or to keep your friends.

Comment: This is what I figured, thanks for clarifying and pretty much clearing up any questions I had about this, it's too bad he doesn't seem to listen to reason, but oh well I guess.